# separate permissions for annotating or editing webform submissions?

Tags: webforms, 9

Is there a way to configure webform admin access that allows annotating/flagging but does not allow altering data submitted by (possibly anonymous) users?

---

I set up a simple webform. I gave a role **View any submissions** access. The role was able to view results but was not able to annotate and flag/star. Firefox console showed error: `The \\u0027administer webform\\u0027 permission is required.`

I gave the role **Administer webform & submissions** access. Now annotation and flagging was allowed but the role also had full ability to alter data submitted which I do not want.

Access seems to be "all or nothing"; I hope I am missing something.

Comment: Which question do you want answered? 

Comment: @cilefen The second sentence is the central query. The other sentences are an attempt to expand that. I'll remove the extra question marks